# Taking a 2D slice of a 3D volume

Tags: opengl, shaders, geometry

I have a regular 3D polygon and I'd like to display 2D slices of it.

What is the best way to achieve this? (Preferrably in OpenGL, but a general algorithm/tecnique would be good as well).

I've already tried by using a camera with narrow z-near/z-far values, but that doesn't seem like a good solution. I don't know if this could be implemented with a custom shader.

Edit: An example of what I'd like to do:

[image]

Kind of the opposite of what is commonly known as 'Volume Rendering'.

Here's an older example: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/941826/2d-slice-from-a-3d-cross-section-slice.html

Comment: The example on fetal.com isn't showcasing 2d from 3d, as the 2d image looks like an ultrasound scan. Typically motion/positional sensors are used alongside 2d image acquisition to produce a 3d volume.

Comment: Try rendering a plane.

Comment: Perhaps use a orthogonal camera inside the object with a very short viewing distance?  This is just a guess tho :/

Comment: This won't work mainly because 3d meshes are only shells. There's no information other than the faces outlining the object. If you want something like the example you posted, you should try to get your hands on some ultrasound data a different depths. I think I remember seeing some freely available online.